# sticky header and footer with scalable div

Tags: jquery, css

i am trying to implement a fixed header and footer with the inner main content to scroll under the header and footer and fix the right navigation.

http://jsfiddle.net/sjUBQ/

the only way i can get as close to this is this http://jsfiddle.net/sjUBQ/ attempt, but i have to fix the height to 300px #main .yui3-u-3-5{background:#aaa;height:300px; overflow:auto;} in order to get the scroll bar.

i tried adding jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var desiredHeight = $("body").height() - $("head").height() - $("footer").height();
  $(".yui3-u-3-5").css("min-height", desiredHeight );
});​
```

but this did not work, so how do i get a sticky header and footer with the inner div showing a scrollbar if the content is higher then the actual browser window?

Comment: Have you tried searching the Internet for "sticky header html"?

Comment: that is not the question! i have the sticky header and footer working, i am interested to know how to fix the height of the inner div and show a scroll bar if the content is bigger without having to set a height to this div as users have different screen sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this kind of what you're going for? http://jsfiddle.net/RiderSargent/sjUBQ/4/

Try changing the height of that lower right pane to see if it behaves the way you want. I think the key (if I understand what you're trying to do correctly) is using `position: fixed;` for your header and footer. You will also probably want to set the top and bottom margins of the main div to the same dimensions you set for the heights of the header and footer respectively.

EDIT: I put the "BEGIN" and "END" in the lorum ipsum to make sure all of it was showing.

EDIT #2: Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RiderSargent/sjUBQ/5/

EDIT #3: In short, I think this is the jQuery you need:

```
var headerHeight = $('#head').height(),
    footerOffset = $('#footer').offset().top,
    desiredHeight = footerOffset - headerHeight;

$('.yui3-u-3-5').css('height', desiredHeight);
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i was trying to figure out how just put the scroll bar for the inner div! i want to have the header, footer and the right column always to show and just have the scrollbar on the inner main content div.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RiderSargent/sjUBQ/5/

Check out the jQuery code to calculate the height of main. If you resize it, then run the jsfiddle, it should do what you want, I think.

I had it output the calculated height into the header for debugging. You should be able to remove the `$('.pad1').text(mainHeight);` line without any trouble.